# Javapoet: Referencing other generated classes

Tags: java, code-generation, javapoet

JavaPoet: Version 1.5.1

JDK: 1.7

I am using annotations to generate the code. Here is something that I am trying.

Following are available as part of the project:

```
@GenService
public abstract class BaseService {
   ...
}

@GenController
public abstract class BaseController {
   ...
}
```

Following are **intended** to be created through the above annotations:

```
public class AService extends BaseService {
   ...
}

public class AController extends BaseController {
   @Autowired
   private AService aService;
   ...
}
```

Until compiled `AService` and `AController` do not exist.

I can include `@Autowired` annotation. But, how do I reference `AService` as a type in `AController`?

Answer (score 2):

Though not direct, I found the answer through Hannes Dorfmann's blog:

[Annotation Processing 101](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101)

The solution goes like this:

```
...
FieldSpec.Builder fsBuilder;
try {
    ClassName clazz = ClassName.get("package.to.services", "AService");
    fsBuilder = FieldSpec.builder(clazz, "aService")
                .addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE)
                .addAnnotation(autowired.build());
} catch (MirroredTypeException mte) {
    DeclaredType classTypeMirror = (DeclaredType) mte.getTypeMirror();
    fsBuilder = FieldSpec.builder(TypeName.get(classTypeMirror), "aService")
                .addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE)
                .addAnnotation(autowired.build());
}
typeBuilder.addField(fsBuilder.build());
```

It worked. But, please do let me know, if there is a better way.

Comment: Thanks! Had a simmilar problem and ClassName.get("package.to.services", "AService"); did the trick for me.